# Sylvester matrix column orthogonality

Tags: induction, hadamard-matrices

I wanted to prove by induction that all sylvester Matrices defined below have orthogonal columns, which seems trivial to see but I wanted a rigorous proof.

$H_0$ = [1] , $H_{i+1}$ = \begin{matrix}
H_i & H_i\\
H_i  & -H_i
\end{matrix}

I first defined the basis step by doing the dot product of $[1,1]^T$ and $[1,-1]^T$ which is obviously 0 which means the columns are orthogonal and the base case holds.

For the Induction Hypothesis I assumed that the hypothesis hold for $H_{i+1}$

and for the induction step I simply replaced in $H_{i+2}$ recursively $H_{i+1}$ and $H_i$ giving me the following :
\begin{matrix}
H_i & H_i & H_i & H_i\\
H_i  & -H_i & H_i  & -H_i\\
H_i  & H_i & -H_i  & -H_i\\
H_i  & -H_i & -H_i  & H_i
\end{matrix}
And I concluded that because each column dot product to another is null , this proved that it holds for every i.
But is it rigorous enough ? I felt like I did not correctly used the IH and would love your opinion about it.
Thank you for reading, and have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base case: $H_0$ has  orthogonal columns.

Induction suppose hypothesis: $H_i$ has orthogonal columns, $H_i^TH_i=D_i$ for some diagonal matrix.

Now to verify if $H_{i+1}$ has orthogonal columns,.

\begin{align}
H_{i+1}^TH_{i+1}&= \begin{bmatrix} H_i & H_i \\ H_i & -H_i \end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix} H_i & H_i \\ H_i & -H_i \end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix} H_i^T & H_i^T \\ H_i^T & -H_i^T \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} H_i & H_i \\ H_i & -H_i \end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 2H_i^TH_i  &0 \\ 0 & 2H_i^TH_i\end{bmatrix} \\
&= 2\begin{bmatrix} D_i  & 0 \\ 0 & D_i\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Hence $H_{i+1}$ has orthogonal columns.

Remark about your attempt:

It is unclear to me why do you do two steps recursion.